# Simulate microarray technical error

Tags: modeling, microarray, synthetic-data

I need to simulate some microarray experiment datasets. I have the levels of expression of a set of synthetic genes in different experimental conditions. For simplicity of the method this levels are relative intensities (0%-100%). I want to use the error model developed by Rocke et al. (link below):

$y=\alpha+\mu e^{\eta}+\epsilon$

where $y$ is the measured gene expression, $\alpha$ is the background level of expression, $\mu$ is the actual level of expression, $\eta \, \tilde{} \, \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma_{\eta} \right)$ is a multiplicative error proportional to the expression level that dominates when the actual level of expression is high and $\epsilon \, \tilde{} \, \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma_{\epsilon} \right)$ is an additive error that dominates when the actual level of expression is low.

To get a microarray expression dataset I need to set these parameters and I would like to get log expression values in range [0,15]

I tried setting $\sigma_{\eta}=0.5$ and $\sigma_{\epsilon}=1$ but in general the range of values obtained depends on the parameters' values.
I cannot find a way to be sure that the expression values are always in that range.

Any suggestions?

http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089%2F106652701753307485

Comment: What is $\beta$? I'd try to call $e^{\eta}$ lognormal, put everything in units of $\alpha$ and plot the allowable region, $f(\eta, \epsilon)$ at your confidence level for your task.

Comment: $\beta$ is a constant that I don't need for this problem. I removed it from the model. Yes, $e^{\eta}$ is a lognormal ditribution. @Jacob Mick, I don't actually get your suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion is to stride over values for $\sigma_{\eta}$, $\mu$ and $\sigma_{epsilon}$ that are normalized by $\alpha$. If I'm understanding the problem correctly, now you can ignore $alpha$. At each iteration sample values and determine how incorrect your recovered $\mu$ is from your underlying $\mu$.

Comment: My very problem is to get an expression value that spans the range [0, 15] independently from the values of $\sigma_{\eta}$ and $\sigma_{\epsilon}$, which is not the case now, for example if I set both sigmas to 1 the $y$ can reach values such as 32